# How to find the Inverse Fourier Transform of a Product of Two Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

after a few hours of trying to solve this problem, I've resorted to asking online.

*"Given that $u\hat(\xi,t)$ is the Fourier Transform of $u(x,t)$ for any each fixed t, and $f\hat(\xi)$ is the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$. Determine the inverse Fourier Transform, $u(x,t)$ of*

$u\hat(\xi,t)=f\hat(\xi)\bullet cos(\xi ct)$

*You may use the translation and convolution properties of Fourier Transforms."*

I assume that I somehow need to find $g(x)$ such that $g\hat(\xi)=cos(\xi ct)$, but the for this function, the Inverse Fourier Equation does not seem to converge.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is related to the *wave equation*. See, for example, the book "Real analysis" of Folland, chapter on Fourier analysis, section on partial differential equations.

Comment: Write $\cos(\xi ct)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\xi ct}+e^{-i\xi ct})$.